# select all not working in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

pls i tried to display all content in a database, it keeps dispaying the last inserted, kindy help out.

```
<?php
            include 'database/condb.php';
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
              $id = $row["id"];
              $username = $row["username"];
              $body =     $row["body"];
              $date_added = $row ["date_added"];
              $hasttags= $row["hashtags"];


           ?>
            <?php
          }
            ?>  

          <?php
          echo $id;
          echo $body;


          ?>
```

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*`API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: put the echo in the while loop not after it

Comment: are you getting any errors? does it work when you query the database directly? what does the current code output?

Comment: @Sebas That is no reason for not giving him this information

Comment: remove space after table name mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ");

Comment: @NikitBarochiya That will not help

Comment: @Jens check now add new code

Answer (score 0):

Either print the values in while loop or store them in an array to print them outside the loop.

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo $row["id"];
    echo $row["body"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    condb.php
    <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","databasename");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    ?>        

    index.php     
    <?php
        include 'database/condb.php';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
        $res = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            $id = $row["id"];
            $username = $row["username"];
            $body =     $row["body"];
            $date_added = $row ["date_added"];
            $hasttags= $row["hashtags"];
        echo $id;
        echo $body;
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: @Jens successfully working this example try run code

Comment: now echo id and body in while loop now work it success

Answer (score 0):

For storing data, sometimes using array becomes helpful. I usually recommend it:

```
<?php
    include 'database/condb.php';
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts");
    $array = [];
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $id = $row["id"];
        $username = $row["username"];
        $body = $row["body"];
        $date_added = $row ["date_added"];
        $hasttags = $row["hashtags"];

        $array[$id] = ['username'=>$username, 'body'=>$body, 'date_added'=>$date_added, 'hasttags'=>$hasttags];
      }
?>

<?php
    foreach($array as $id => $value){
        echo $id; //Prints id
        echo "<br>";
        echo $value['username'].", ".$value['body'].", ".$value['date_added'].", ".$value['hasttags'];
    }
?>
```

Or you can simply do this:

```
<?php
    include 'database/condb.php';
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts");
    $array = [];
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $id = $row["id"];
        $username = $row["username"];
        $body = $row["body"];
        $date_added = $row ["date_added"];
        $hasttags = $row["hashtags"];
?>

<?php
        echo $id.", ".$username.", ".$body.", ".$date_added.", ".$hasttags;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please carefully see where while loop ends(focus on brackets)

Answer (score 0):

```
         <?php
         include 'database/condb.php';
          $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ");
          while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
          $id = $row["id"];
          $username = $row["username"];
          $body =     $row["body"];
          $date_added = $row ["date_added"];
          $hasttags= $row["hashtags"];

            echo $id;
             echo "<br>";
            echo $body;
       ?>
        <?php
      }
        ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

As an answer to the question "pls i tried to display all content in a database, it keeps dispaying the last inserted, kindy help out."

Put echo $id, echo $body be inside the loop.